# Как получить html DIV'a через WebBrowser?

Tags: webbrowser, delphi, delphi-7, html

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить html DIV'a через WebBrowser (компонент стандартный)

```
webbrowser1.oleobject.document.getelementbyid('idelementa').innerHTML
```

Вот так находит если есть у этого элемента атрибут

```
ID="idelementa"
```

а как быть, если у DIV'a есть только "класс" то есть

```
class="class class2"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var
  i, j: integer;
  FormItem: Variant;
begin

  for i := 0 to WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.Forms.Length - 1 do
  begin

    FormItem := WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.Forms.Item(i);
    for j := 0 to FormItem.Length - 1 do
    begin
      try
        // если найденно изменить.
        if FormItem.Item(j).**Name** = **что нужно** then
        begin

 // Вот здесь ваш код
вместо **name** можно использовать ID,CLASS,TYPE

        end;
      except
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```