# Как проверить в Delphi существует ли элемент в HTML странице?

Tags: delphi-7, delphi, webbrowser, html

Например, если существует на странице

```
<div id="test">text</div>
```

То,

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getelementbyid('test').value:='333';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.getelementbyid('test')

// to do
```

[Как получить html DIV'a через WebBrowser?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/144202/delphi-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-div-a-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-webbrowser) - может что-то интересное найдете

Comment: Пробовал, не работает!